# align an html canvas to absolute top of the web page

Tags: javascript, html, css, layout

I would like to know how to align a canvas element to the absolute top ( 0 , 0 ) of the web page.

I have tried:  `margin: 0; padding: 0px;` but no good.

There's always some white space at the top.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Make sure your "body" and "html" have no padding:

```
body, html { padding: 0; margin: 0; }
```

Then make sure the canvas is either "naturally" positioned at the top, or else is absolutely positioned.

Comment: @nubegeek101 Welcome to Stack Overflow! Know that while 'thanks' are always welcome, the best way to thank someone for helping you is to a) upvote their answer (click the triangle) if it was helpful, and b) accept their answer (click the checkmark) if it solved your question.

Answer (score 1):

Consider using a reset.css when designing web pages, this will clear out any and all default styles that most browsers will inject as default. I like this one: http://yuilibrary.com/yui/docs/cssreset/